# Android: identificar una SD card fisica y escribir en ella

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema que me está costando bastante entender.

Estoy trabajando en un app que debe controlar el espacio de almacenamiento del dispositivo para poder realizar sus procesos habituales, además de ello; la aplicación debe poder identificar si existe una tarjeta SD física (insertada en la ranura) y priorizar su uso en lugar del espacio externo emulado.

He leído bastante y he probado muchos ejemplos y el resultado es el mismo, lo detallo a continuación:

1. Siempre el telefono indica que el espacio externo es emulado
2. Aunque tenga una tarjeta SD en la ranura, el app no la usa, no la identifica por lo anterior.
3. Por consiguiente no he encontrado la manera de calcular el espacio disponible para los tipos de almacenamiento: interno (el que usan las apps /data/data), externo emulado (si no tengo SD), externo real (si tengo la SD)

Para guardar un archivo a la SD (supuestamente) uso la sentencia

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name);
```

en donde `name` es un `String` con el nombre del archivo. El archivo se crea **siempre** en el espacio externo **emulado**, no importa que tenga una SD en la ranura, no la usa. De acuerdo a [esto](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-file-to-sd-card), esa debe ser la forma correcta.

El método `isExternalStorageEmulated()` siempre retorna `true` y el método `isExternalStorageRemovable()` siempre retorna `false`

Me curo en salud de lo siguiente:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();// siempre es "mounted" con SD o no presente
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    ...
}
```

Incluso de esto:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

En todos los lugares que he consultado, estos métodos hacen su trabajo, pero no entiendo en mi caso porque no puedo lograr el resultado que quiero.

He probado mi app en los siguientes dispositivos:

1. LG L5 (Android 4+)
2. Sony Xperia (Android 4+)
3. Alcatel Pop 2 (Android 5)

El resultado ha sido el mismo. En concreto, las preguntas a solventar serían:

1. ¿Cómo identificar "realmente" la presencia de una SD física?
2. ¿Cómo escribir "realmente" un archivo a una SD física?

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde yo se la ruta de la SD depende del fabricante. Yo de momento he encontrado estas 3 rutas:
/storage/sdcard1/
/storage/extsd/
/mnt/external_sd/

Es poco util hacer esto (A mi me vale por que trabajo con pocos fabricantes).
En este hilo hablan de una función que devuelve la ruta, aun que a mi solo me devuelve "null".

[Como guardar y leer directamente en la scard](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8625/como-guardar-y-leer-directamente-en-la-scard)

```
String sdPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Tu punto es correcto y de hecho es lo que estoy haciendo, ya que lo había consultado con alguien del site en inglés. Respuesta aceptada, aunque esta gente deberá de alguna manera poder especificar bien esto en la documentación; ya que todo lo que dice la doc es lo que precisamente no funciona.

Comment: Una posible solución, que aun no he probado, podría ser recorrer las carpetas de la ruta /storage/ y descartar las que son genéricas de Android como emulated, sdcard0 o ¿usbotg?.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente hay que revisar si la SD Card esta "montada":

```
    if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))   {
        Log.i("SDCARDINFO","SD Card se encuentra presente.");
   } else {
        Log.i("SDCARDINFO","No se encuentra SD Card.");
   }
```

Editando....

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta, con ese punto. No es valido para este caso, ya que si lo estoy comprobando.