# Como guardar y leer directamente en la scard

Tags: android

Buenas tardes

Soy nuevo en la programación en android, y en estos momentos estoy desarrollando una App que me lea y escriba archivos txt en la tarjeta sd, solo que ya me atore, puesto que al intentar leer el archivo siempre me arroja la excepción de "File Not Found" ya lo intente de varias formas y siempre es el mismo mensaje, el archivo existe en la SD en la ruta que indico, pero no lo encuentra, utilizando esta instrucción:

```
File SD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

me arroja la ruta:

```
"/storage/emulated/0"
```

ya con el nombre de mi archivo queda:

```
"/storage/emulated/0/datos.txt"
```

pero no lo encuetra, en una pagina de consulta vi, que indicaban que esta ruta indica el almacenamiento externo pero emulado y no la ruta real de la SD real montada en la ranura, en el código realizo la validación de la SD montada y me devuelve un true, este es el código con el que intento abrir el archivo:

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals("mounted")) {
    File SD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (SD.canRead()) {
        File file = new File(SD.getAbsolutePath(), "datos.txt");
        try {
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
```

y el error me lo arroja siempre en la ultima línea, ya intente en un equipo Sony Xperia C4, con android 5.1 y en un Huawei Mate 8 con android 6.0 y el resultado es el mismo, tambien tengo establecidos los permisos en el manifests, inclusive puse los de read y los write:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

y el resultado es el siempre el mismo, que podría ser...? que me falta hacer...?, gracias...

Comment: Ya lo solucione, en lugar de usar "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();" use System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE"); y eso me da la ruta de la SD... espero esto les pueda servir a muchos...

Comment: Si encontraste una solución compártela como respuesta, así los demás pueden encontrarla útil.

Answer (score 1):

Publicado en un [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8625/como-guardar-y-leer-directamente-en-la-scard#comment15398_8625) por el OP:

> Ya lo solucione, en lugar de usar "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();" use System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE"); y eso me da la ruta de la SD... espero esto les pueda servir a muchos..