# ¿como acceder a la ruta de la tarjeta externa en android 6.0 adelante?

Tags: android

Pues lo dicho, no soy capaz de acceder a la ruta de la tarjeta sd, me devuelve la ruta /emulated/0 q es la de la memoria interna.
un saludo y espero vuestra ayuda!!
adjunto el codigo

```
public void grabar(){
    String nomarchivo = et1.getText().toString();
    String contenido = et2.getText().toString();

    try {
        File tarjeta = Environment.getDataDirectory();

       Toast.makeText(this, getExternalFilesDir(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()).getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        File file = new File(s,nomarchivo);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
        osw.write(contenido);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Los datos fueron grabados correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        et1.setText("");
        et2.setText(s);}
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo grabar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido MR. PUNK!, estaba dándo por **posible duplicado** tu pregunta, pero debido a que el OP que hizo la pregunta [¿Cómo guardar y leer directamente en la scard?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8625/como-guardar-y-leer-directamente-en-la-scard) no respondió su propia pregunta, ya no pude reportarte. En dicha pregunta el OP tuvo tu mismo problema pero la solución del problema lo puso como comentario.

Comment: Davlio: En relación a lo de las respuestas publicadas en comentarios, he publicado una [pregunta en meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1454/65). Se propone pasar la respueta del comentario a una respuesta, lo cual recién realicé (puse la respuesta como wiki de comunidad).

Comment: @Rubén te olvidaste del `@` para notificar =). Lo tendré en cuenta de ahora en adelante. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a la ruta del **almacenamiento externo** debes usar [getExternalFilesDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))

Para acceder a la ruta del **almacenamiento interno** debes user [getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir())

Estas usando [getExternalFilesDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) y reportas que te devuelve la ruta `/emulated/0` , definitivamente estas en el almacenamiento externo, la ruta del almacenamiento externo es similar a `data/data`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Te sugiero revisar:

[**Como detectar y obtener la ruta de la SDcard en un dispositivo Android**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/121592/95)

**Detectar si existe una SDCard instalada y montada**:

```
public static boolean isSDCardAvailable(Context context) {
    File[] storages = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
    if (storages.length > 1 && storages[0] != null && storages[1] != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**Obtener la ruta de la SDCard**:

```
public static String getSDCardPath(Context context) {
    File[] storages = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
    if (storages.length > 1 && storages[0] != null && storages[1] != null){
        return storages[1].getAbsolutePath();
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar este método, en storage[0] tendrás la ruta de almacenamiento interno y en storage[1] tendrás la ruta de tu sd

```
public static boolean isSDCardAvailable(Context context) {
         storages = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
        if (storages.length > 1 && storages[0] != null && storages[1] != null) {
            Log.d("isSDCardAvailable: ", "Ruta :" + storages[0].getPath()+storages[1]);
            path=storages[1].getPath();
            path=path.substring(0,19);
            Log.d("isSDCardAvailable: ", "Ruta :" + path);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En realidad lo correcto es obtener todo el path del SDCard, ya que no se podrá acceder a leer o escribir afuera de la estructura que crea la aplicación: ...Android/data/<Package name>/files. Agregué aquí el método para obtener la ruta del SDCard https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/121592/95