# getExternalStorageDirectory devuelve true en teléfono sin microsd

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Intento consultar el estado del almacenamiento externo a través de la siguiente función:

```
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Sin embargo, me devuelve `true` ejecutando la app en un teléfono sin entrada para microSD. Al imprimir `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, aparece la dirección `/storage/emulated/0`, la cual no existe en el dispositivo.

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de esto?¿Cómo se podría solucionar?

Comment: espero mi respuesta te aclare la duda

Comment: Agrego una explicación de porque obtienes siempre true @Acentellao17 , la razón es que tu método solo revisa si tienes almacenamiento externo presente, lo cual es común en los dispositivos android actualmente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Siendo sincero, esto es algo que me intrigaba, ¿porque si no tengo montada una SD Card al revisar su estado siempre me mostraba que estaba presente?

```
 String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

Aunque revisando la configuración me indica que no esta montada y más extraño aún, que no inserte ninguna SD Card!.

#### Como detectar si la SD card esta presente en un dispositivo Android

Bien pues la razón es que actualmente casi todos los dispositivos cuentan con memoria externa la cual se considera como "primaria", si insertamos una SD Card ahora tendríamos una memoria externa "secundaria".

por lo tanto **para detectar si existe una SD Card instalada y montada, este sería un método indicado**:

```
public static boolean isSDCardAvailable(Context context) {
    File[] storages = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
    if (storages.length > 1 && storages[0] != null && storages[1] != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

La explicación es, si no tienes insertada una SD Card, únicamente se tiene el almacenamiento externo "primario", por lo tanto solo un directorio de almacenamiento externo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, si insertamos una SD Card, se tendra el almacenamiento externo "primario" y el almacenamiento en la SD Card, por lo tanto dos directorios de almacenamiento externo, si tienes más de uno indica que tienes una SD card montada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Como obtener la ruta de la SD card

De acuerdo a lo anterior, el método para obtener la ruta donde se encuentra la SDCard sería:

```
public static String getSDCardPath(Context context) {
    File[] storages = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
    if (storages.length > 1 && storages[0] != null && storages[1] != null){
        return storages[1].getAbsolutePath();
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

---

Usando los métodos anteriores, podemos primeramente detectar si existe la SDCard y posteriormente obtener su ruta:

```
Log.i(TAG, "isSDCardAvailable ? " + isSDCardAvailable(getApplicationContext()));
if(isSDCardAvailable(getApplicationContext())){//Existe la SDCard ?
    Log.i(TAG, "The SDCard path is: " + getSDCardPath(getApplicationContext()));
}
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
isSDCardAvailable ? true
The SDCard path is: /storage/17D1-123B/Android/data/com.jorgesys.javahacks/files
```

Answer (score -1):

El external directory no necesariamente indica que el teléfono/tablet tiene una SD Card, si los equipos no tienen SD Card, ese valor puede retornar true, solo indica que ese espacio se puede usar para escribir/guardar archivos como si fuera una SD Card, ya que hay una partición que solo es usada para archivos del sistema.

Para diferenciar si `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` realmente retorna el almacenamiento interno o externo, llama a `Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated()`. Si es emulado, entonces es interno. En dispositivos nuevos que tienen almacenamiento interno y ranura para tarjeta SD, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` siempre devolverá el almacenamiento interno. Mientras que en dispositivos antiguos que solo tienen sdcard como una opción de almacenamiento de medios, siempre devolverá la tarjeta SD.

Aquí la documentación y el enlace:

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

[External Directory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

Comment: gracias Diego, comprendo que external directory no hace referencia específicamente a una tarjeta SD. Aún tengo la duda de porqué `getExternalStorageDirectory()` me devuelve una ruta inexistente, ¿será problema del dispositivo?

Comment: hmm "/storage/emulated/0" es la ruta que usa para montar el disco, no hay problema con eso, si te sirvió mi respuesta la puedes marcar como resuelta, ya que veo varios negativos sin razón :). gracias

Comment: ¿ Por que el -2 ?

Comment: @AshleyG. no idea :D

Comment: @AshleyG. no se pueden dar -2, aquí 2 usuarios votaron en contra =/.

Comment: Creo que hay que buscar la forma o presentar una idea para ver quien vota negativamente ... @Jorgesys no hay control :/

Answer (score -1):

La razón por la que siempre se retorna true se debe a que Android particiona la memoria interna física, creando una partición primaria no accesible y una partición secundaria que emula una memoria externa que de hecho cuando accedes a carpetas como downloads, pictures etc estas accediendo a esta partición emulada.

Estando presente o no una SDCard esta partición siempre va a existir en las nuevas versiones de Android.

Agrego que la respuesta de @JorgeSys no esta del todo completa yo agregaría el método `Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable("File_path")`como una validación adicional, este devolverá false con la ruta "storage/emulated/0" ya que es una partición de la memoria interna y por lo tanto no se puede remover a diferencia de una SDCard que su ruta de acceso devolverá true es decir que es almacenamiento desmostable o removible.