# mkdirs() no me crea carpetas en tarjeta sd

Tags: android, android-studio, archivo, mkdir

Buenos días programadores ("los magos"). Voy a lo siguiente: Necesito crear archivos en la tarjeta sD, siempre que lo intento crear termina creandome en la memoria del teléfono y no en la sd externa. Mi código es lo siguiente:

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Psinapsis/Imagenes/Inventario"
File dir = new File(file_path);

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"file_path existe NO");
        dir.mkdirs();
        Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"dirTrue:" + dir.mkdirs());//devuelve FALSO :(
    }
```

lo he argregado los siguientes permisos en el manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

También ya le probé generar los permisos en tiempo de ejecución:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tengo permiso",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

¿Qué he hecho mal? :(
obs: ya le probé con mkdir(), igual nada

Comment: probaste con getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: Sí lo he probado. igual me crea en la interna del telefono

Comment: Creo que algunos dispositivos tenían configurado la memoria interna como si fuera una de tipo SD, por eso te está cogiendo la primera. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219312/android-open-external-storage-directorysdcard-for-storing-file

Comment: Te recomiendo le heches un vistazo a la siguiente respuesta que se encuentra en SO en Ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3853814/5520161

Comment: Joel, Si insertamos una SD Card, se tendra el almacenamiento externo "primario" y el almacenamiento en la SD Card, por lo tanto dos directorios de almacenamiento externo, si tienes más de uno indica que tienes una SD card montada.

Comment: Tengo sólo la tarjeta SD, en el dispositivo LG G4 Stylus, no se si se necesita alguna configuración adicional en el movil

Comment: hasta ahora solo me guarda en la memoria del teléfono

Comment: en memoria del teléfono podría saber a que ruta te refieres?

Comment: el Log.i me arroja esto /storage/emulated/0/Psinapsis/Imagenes/Inventario/Imag.jpg

Comment: ingreso en mi Explorador de Archivo del movil y encuentro la ruta creada en la memora del teléfono.. no en la tarjeta sd

Comment: @JoelRomero el problema es ese, esa ruta en realidad es de almacenamiento externo pero no de la SDCard, revisa mi respuesta agregué un método para detectar si tienes SDCard y de esta forma obtener la ruta! :)

Answer (score 1):

No hay duda que tienes el permiso requerido, este no es el problema.

En este caso tienes 2 rutas de almacenamiento externo:

Si insertamos una SD Card, se tendra el almacenamiento externo "primario" y el almacenamiento en la SD Card, por lo tanto dos directorios de almacenamiento externo, si tienes más de uno indica que tienes una SD card montada.

[getExternalStorageDirectory devuelve true en teléfono sin microsd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121467/getexternalstoragedirectory-devuelve-true-en-tel%C3%A9fono-sin-microsd)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De acuerdo a lo anterior:

**Primeramente revisa si en realidad tienes una SDCard y esta montada**, para esto puedes usar este método:

```
public static boolean hasRealRemovableSdCard(Context context) {
    return ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null).length >= 2;
}
```

**si existe entonces obtén el path para que en esta ruta guardes tus archivos**:

```
public static String getRemovableSDCardPath(Context context) {
    File[] storages = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
    if (storages.length > 1 && storages[0] != null && storages[1] != null)
        return storages[1].toString();
    else
        return "";
}
```

Este sería un ejemplo de acuerdo a tu código:

```
if(hasRealRemovableSdCard(getApplicationContext())){
    String file_path =  getRemovableSDCardPath(getApplicationContext()) +"/Psinapsis/Imagenes/Inventario";
    File dir = new File(file_path);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        Log.i(TAG,"file_path NO existe, lo crea.");
        Log.i(TAG,"dirTrue:"  + dir.mkdirs());
    }
}
```

Comment: el Log me lanza esta ruta: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.joelii.sinapsis/files

Comment: tengo puesta la tarjeta sd. yo puedo acceder a su contenido desde la galeria.

Comment: La ruta que muestras es del almacenamiento externo pero no de la SDCard, realizalo con los métodos de la respuesta.para obtener el path del almacenamiento en la SDCard.

Comment: Jorgesy String getRemovableSDCardPath(Context context) me devuelve vacío. esperoseguir contando con tu ayuda.. Lo implementé el método que me has indicado y devuelve vacio.. que podría ser?

Comment: el Log me devuelve file_path: /Psinapsis/Imagenes/Inventario

Comment: @JoelRomero debes revisar primeramente que obtienes con el método: hasRealRemovableSdCard()

Comment: ese metodo devuelve true.  estoy usando un dispositivo fisico LG G4 Stylus para las pruebas de la app

Comment: Si usas os 6.0 o mayor ya requeriste los permisos manualmente?

Comment: El dispositivo mencionado usa versión de Android 5.0.2