# Aclaración del funcionamiento de Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() en Android

Tags: android

He leído algunos tutoriales Android y me dicen que el método `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` me devuelve la ruta al directorio de mi tarjeta SD, el asunto es que no tengo tarjeta SD y este método me está devolviendo la ruta a mi almacenamiento interno, mi pregunta es: ¿ Este método me devuelve el almacenamiento interno o externo, como funciona esto ?

Comment: hasta donde se te da la ruta a la sd externa siempre este montada, en caso contrario va a la interna [VER TEMA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5453753/7621631)

Answer (score -1):

> He leído algunos tutoriales Android y me dicen que el método 
>    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() me devuelve la ruta al
>   directorio de mi tarjeta SD, el asunto es que no tengo tarjeta SD

No necesariamente es la ruta de tu SD Card, en realidad cuando insertas una tarjeta SD, la mayoría de los dispositivos crean otra ruta de almacenamiento externo ya que el dispositivo cuenta con una propia.

Como ejemplo esta imagen en donde se muestra que al insertar la SD Card podemos detectar 2 rutas para almacenamiento externo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿ Este método me devuelve el almacenamiento interno o externo, como
>   funciona esto ?

**En realidad [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) devuelve el directorio principal de almacenamiento compartido / externo.**
Si no tienes una SD card insertada y montada, obtendrá la ruta del almacenamiento externo con el que cuenta el dispositivo.

Te sugiero revisar esta pregunta relacionada:

[getExternalStorageDirectory devuelve true en teléfono sin microsd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121467/getexternalstoragedirectory-devuelve-true-en-tel%C3%A9fono-sin-microsd/121592#121592)

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.