# ¿Como obtener el path de la sdcard en Android?

Tags: java, android

primero quiero aclarar porque realizo esta pregunta, se que ya se ha preguntado bastante sobre esta problemática en esta comunidad, ya he consultado muchas dudas anteriores y ninguna me ha llegado a ayudar. 
Me he estado introduciendo recientemente en Android, he llegado a la temática de "Escritura y lectura" en memoria interna y externa, pero he tenido problemas a la hora de intentar escribir o leer en la memoria externa. Estos problemas a la vez me han causado cierta confusión. A continuación redacto mis problemas:

(API que utilizo: 23)
- Me he estado guiando mediante la documentación oficial de Android [Almacenamiento externo](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=es-419#filesExternal)
aquí se menciona dos métodos muy útiles por la descripción que se le contribuyen "getExternalStorageDirectory()" y "getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(type)". Para probar dichos métodos he intentado crear una aplicación simple, la cual consiste en crear un directorio de prueba dentro del directorio publico "Pictures", aquí el código que utilizo en mi MainActivity.java para realizar dicha acción:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView output;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath()+"/Prueba");
        if(directory.mkdirs()){
            output.setText("Hecho!");
        }
      }
    }
```

Como se puede apreciar en el código no es nada complejo lo que intento, mis problemas y a la vez mi dudas son las siguientes:
Mi aplicación escribe el directorio solicitado en la memoria interna del teléfono, es decir, utiliza la siguiente ruta "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures" obtenida  por el método "getExternalStoragePublicDirectory" de la clase "Environment" haciendo imposible escribir en la memoria sd. Dicho lo anterior refleja mi problema al no permitirme escribir en la memoria sd, mis dudas surgen cuando investigo las razones para devolver esa ruta (para aclarar tengo noción hasta ahora por lo que he investigado el cambio que han tenido las apis en este tema). Algunas fuentes instruyen que la razón se debe a que la ruta señalada por "emulated" es un directorio instanciado para los dos tipos de almacenamiento, es decir, interno y externo 
¿Que tan cierto es esto? 
¿Si esto es cierto entonces siempre accederé a la memoria interna? 
En el caso de que estos métodos siempre me conduzcan a la memoria interna ¿Como podría acceder realmente a la memoria externa (sdcard)?

Tuve algunos indicios de avance al utilizar "ContextCompat" utilizando el método:

> ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this,null);

Esto me ha regresado un arreglo de tipo "File" que describe todas los directorios a los que mi app puede acceder, entre ellos he notado que uno me conduce a "/storage/5690-0394/Android/data/com.isaac.Prueba/files" dicho directorio hace referencia a la memoria SD correctamente mas en especifico por las rutas padre "/storage/5690-0394/".

De verdad esto me ha causado una fuerte confusión, ahora no entiendo que es realmente "/storage/emulated" y si realmente sirven de algo los métodos que la clase Environment proporciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el path de la SDCard puedes usar:

```
String pathSDCard = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
```

Puedes usar un método para detectar si tu dispositivo cuenta con SDCard:

```
public static boolean isSDCardAvailable(Context context) {
    File[] storages = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
    if (storages.length > 1 && storages[0] != null && storages[1] != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

considero demasiado importante revises esta información:

[getExternalStorageDirectory devuelve true en teléfono sin microsd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121467/getexternalstoragedirectory-devuelve-true-en-tel%C3%A9fono-sin-microsd/121592#121592)

Comment: Te agradezco, mil gracias por tu aportación <3 Solo me resta una duda, busque en la documentación este método "getenv()" y se especificaba que solo es funcional cuando el sistema acepta variables de entorno ¿crees que se de el caso donde android no permita tal cosa? De cualquier forma reitero mi agradecimiento, tu aportación me ha sido de mucha ayuda.