# ¿Cómo crear un archivo txt en la memoria externa (MICRO-SD)?

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente código para crear un archivo TXT en la memoria externa (MICRO-SD), pero no funciona, no puedo crear el archivo. Nunca encuentro el archivo en la memoria SD. Realizo las pruebas en un teléfono celular con Android 7.0

También tengo los permisos definidos en AndroidManifest.xml para permitir que se cree el archivo, pero todavía no funciona para mí.

Realmente agradecería si me ayudas a entender por qué no funciona para mí o si tengo un código incorrecto. Gracias

```
File ruta_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

File f = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath(), "bitacora.txt");


    try {

    OutputStreamWriter fout = new OutputStreamWriter(new 
    FileOutputStream(f,true));
        //cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        //String fecha=cal.get(cal.DATE)+"-"+cal.get((cal.MONTH)+1) +"- 
  "+cal.get(cal.YEAR);
        String fecha=cal.get(cal.DATE)+"-"+cal.get((cal.MONTH)) +"- 
  "+cal.get(cal.YEAR);
        String hora=cal.get(cal.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"
     +cal.get(cal.MINUTE)+":"+cal.get(cal.SECOND);

        fout.write("Linea numero:   -  "+fecha+"  -  "+hora+"\n");
        fout.write( "\n" );
        fout.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Ficheros", "error");
    }

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
  />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Las 2 últimas lineas que muestras están en la clase?

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, No, están en el AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Me parece entonces que el problema es que no los has requerido manualmente , revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-android-6-0-read-external/24934#24934

Comment: Jorgesys mil gracias, no sabia de ese truco, ya me permite crear y ver el archivo, tan solo una curiosidad mas, por qué me crea el archivo en la memoria interna y no en la MICRO-SD? No es para eso que se emplea la instrucción getExternalStorageDirectory? gracias

Comment: Si la respuesta pudo resolver el problema marca como solucion y vota, revisa [tour]. Con respecto a tu pregunta, en realidad es la ruta de almacenamiento externo pero este puede ser del dispositivo o de u Sdcard si esta montada, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121467/getexternalstoragedirectory-devuelve-true-en-teléfono-sin-microsd